# Batch command for deleting first and last columns of a text file

Tags: windows-7

I have data in the first and last columns of a tab delimited text file. I want the first and last columns of the file to be deleted using batch. I have tried it using `cut` command, but it is not supported by Windows.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441827/windows-command-for-cutting-columns-from-a-text) is  an answer for a very similar question. Or you can find a Windows port of cut [there](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

- Input data is in 4 columns separated by tabs (column 3 has embedded spaces).
- If data values do not have spaces then `delims=<tab>` is optional.
- Source filename does not have spaces (but output filename may if enclosed: "File 2 Col Out.txt")

Run Command Prompt and enter (substituting actual tab keystroke instead of `<tab>` in two places):

```
CMD /f:off
FOR /f "tokens=2,3 delims=<tab>" %B in (TabFile.txt) do @echo %B<tab>%C>> 2ColFile.txt  
CMD /f:on
```

Example:

```
c:\DeleteMe>type tabfile.txt
123     ABC     Ap ple   321
135     BDF     Bro wn   642
c:\DeleteMe>CMD /f:off
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\DeleteMe>FOR /f "tokens=2,3 delims=  " %B in (TabFile.txt) do @echo %B       %C>> 2ColFile.txt    
c:\DeleteMe>type 2colfile.txt
ABC     Ap ple
BDF     Bro wn
c:\DeleteMe>CMD /f:on
```